# Isotope v2 with Angular cli

Tags: angular, npm, jquery-isotope, angular2-modules

I'm exepiencing problems using isotope-layout module with angular cli

I installed the module with
npm install isotope-layout --save

and I added the script in my .angular-cli.json file

```
"scripts": [ 
    ...
    "../node_modules/isotope-layout/dist/isotope.pkgd.js"
  ],
```

and also the dependancy in the package.json

```
 "dependencies": {
    ..
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4",
    "isotope-layout": "^3.0.2"
 }
```

but if I call in my component

```
ngOnInit() { $('.grid').isotope(); }
```

but I have back an error

```
Property 'isotope' does not exist on type 'jQuery<HTMLElement>'
```

How can I use this library in my module?
I tried to import it with

```
import isotope from 'isotope-layout';
```

but I have the error "cannot find module"

Can anyone explain to me how to use angular module in angular cli? I'm preatty confused..

ps_If via console I type `$('.grid').isotope();` it works..

Answer (score 7):

The install command and your cli config look correct.

I think first you have to make 'Isotope' visible by adding a type definition.

```
declare var Isotope: any;
```

You can do that in the typings.d.ts file or directly in your component.ts file.
Then you can use it in the code like that i.e. when clicking a button.

```
sortButtonClick(){

  let grid = document.querySelector('.grid');
  let iso = new Isotope(grid, {
      sortBy: 'random'
    }
  );
}
```